# WCF Post method how to pass a objects with datetime properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I have an issue when passing an object into WCF service from client side using C#.  The object contains datetime properties. While I am passing properties, getting error with datetime properties. Its working fine when I am sending properties other than datetime properties. Please guide me to solve this problem.

Value object :

```
[DataContract]
public class TestVO
{
    [DataMember]
    public long TEST_ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TEST_NO { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TEST_DATE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long CREATED_BY { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CREATED_ON { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public long UPDATED_BY { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? UPDATED_ON { get; set; }
}
```

Data transmission object

```
[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public TestVO objTest { get; set; }
}
```

WCF method :

```
    public void GetTest(Test objTest, string strTest1)
    {
        dynamic response;

    }
```

WCF service method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetTest/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void GetTest(Test objTest, string strTest1)
```

Client side:

```
 try
        {    
            Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:91/MPOSService.svc/web/GetTest/");

            // Create the web request  
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Set type to POST  
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            Test objTest = new Test();

            TestVO objTestVO = new TestVO();

            objTestVO.TEST_ID = 1;
            objTestVO.TEST_NO="TT001";
            objTestVO.TEST_DATE = DateTime.Now;
            objTestVO.CREATED_BY = 1;
            objTestVO.CREATED_ON = DateTime.Now;

            objTest.Test=objTestVO;

            JObject jsonNew = new JObject();
            jsonNew.Add("objTest", JToken.FromObject(objTest));
            jsonNew.Add("strTest1", JToken.FromObject("1"));

            string data2 = jsonNew.ToString();


            // Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
            byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data2);

            // Set the content length in the request headers  
            request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

            // Write data  
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

**Error:**
**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

Comment: I think you may need to decorate your `Test`/`TestVO` classes with `[Serializable]`. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183866.aspx) (sorry, I don't have full access to test this.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already, you may want to consider enabling WCF activity tracing, which should provide some additional details regarding the server side error.

The following article provides a good overview of WCF Tracing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx